# WPF Listview Groups Headers Not Displaying: Any Ideas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

Below is the XAML. The data from the object is populating the listview. I just can't get the groups to display. I want to group on a property called workcenter, which isn't displayed in the listview, but it's still part of the class bound to it.

I'm a WPF noob, so forgive me if the answer is right in front of me and I'm missing it. I'm using examples from the web to try to get this to work but it's just not to this point.

This is a mock-up for a project I have to do, so ignore the silly form text and namespace. =)

```
<Window x:Class="Son_of_a_Batching_WPF_Mock_up.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="You Son of a Batch. I'm Detective John Kimble! I'm A Cop You Idiot!" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding testDataCollection}" 
                              x:Key="src">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="workcenter" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="White">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboWorkCenters" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="256" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="12,50,0,0" SelectedIndex="0" FontSize="12pt" Height="27.28"> 
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Group by work center" FontSize="12pt"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Group by batch type" FontSize="12pt"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label x:Name="lblFilter" FontSize ="12pt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11.473,13.043,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Filter by work center:" Width="252.527" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lvBatches" Margin="12,83,12,12" ItemsSource="{Binding Source = {StaticResource src}}"><!--ItemsSource="{Binding testDataCollection}">-->

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="    {Binding Path=name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="    {Binding Path=itemcount}"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colID" Header="Batch ID" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>
                    <!--<GridViewColumn x:Name="colWC" Header="Work Center" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding workcenter}"/>-->
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colStart" Header="Start Time" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding start}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colEnd" Header="End Time" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding end}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colDur" Header="Duration" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding duration}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colBatchType" Header="Batch Type" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding batchtype}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Since I can't post images, I'll try to map out how it looks using text skills. What I get is this:

```
**Batch ID  Start Time  End Time    Duration    Batch Type**
--------    ----------  --------    --------    ----------
12344555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
54564564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
12433555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
54564564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
12311555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
54456564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
12344555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
57744564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
12994555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
54500564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
```

What I want is this, with 332, 404 being the groups.

```
**Batch ID  Start Time  End Time    Duration    Batch Type**
--------    ----------  --------    --------    ----------
**332**
12344555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
12433555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded
12311555    7/21/11     7/22/11     100     Loaded

**404**
54564564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
54564564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
54500564    7/21/11     7/23/11     50      Sequential
```

Here's the code behind. I don't think it'll help. Most of it is just test data to display in the mock-up.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Son_of_a_Batching_WPF_Mock_up
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TestData> _testDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();
        public ObservableCollection<TestData> testDataCollection { get { return _testDataCollection; } }
        //public System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView source { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.source.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("workcenter"));

            LoadTestData();

        }

        private void LoadTestData()
        {
            //int[] icnt = new int[529];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            {
                _testDataCollection.Add(new TestData());
            }
            //for (int i = 0; i < _testDataCollection.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    icnt[int.Parse(_testDataCollection[i].workcenter)] ++;
            //}   
            //this.label1.Content = "332:" + icnt[332].ToString() + "," + "402:" + icnt[402].ToString() + ","+ "404:" + icnt[404].ToString() + ","
            //       + "522:" + icnt[522].ToString() + ","+ "523:" + icnt[523].ToString() + ","+ "524:" + icnt[524].ToString() + ","
            //       + "527:" + icnt[527].ToString() + ","+ "528:" + icnt[528].ToString() + ",";
        }
    }

    public class TestData
    {
        private string[] _WCs = new string[] { "404", "527", "523", "524", "332", "528", "522", "402" };
        private string[] _workcenters = new string[1000];
        private string _workcenter;
        private double _duration = 0;

        public string id
        {
            get { return Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
        }

        public string workcenter
        {
            get
            {
                return _workcenter;
            }
        }

        public DateTime start
        {
            get { return DateTime.Now; }
        }

        public DateTime end
        {
            get { return DateTime.Now; }
        }

        public double duration
        {
            get
            {
                return _duration;
            }
        }

        public string batchtype
        {
            get
            {
                switch (workcenter)
                {
                    case "332":
                    case "402":
                    case "527":
                        return "Loaded Batch";
                    case "404":
                    case "524":
                        return "Sequential Batch";
                    case "522":
                    case "528":
                    case "523":
                        return "Supervisor Batch";
                    default:
                        return "";
                }
            }
        }

        public TestData()
        {
            RandomizeWCs();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            _workcenter = _workcenters[rnd.Next(0, 999)];
            rnd = new Random();
            _duration = rnd.Next(10, 60);
        }

        private void RandomizeWCs()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int iIndex, i;

            while (_workcenters.Contains(null))
            {
                iIndex = rnd.Next(1000);
                i = rnd.Next(8);
                if (_workcenters[iIndex] == null)
                {
                    _workcenters[iIndex] = _WCs[i];
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does display, anything at all?

Comment: I get everything to group correctly now, only the group text isn't displaying. So, basically the example below 'What I want is this, with 332, 404 being the groups.' only without the **332** and **404** displaying. I can't post images yet, unfortunately.

Comment: You get my vote for the "Son_of_a_Batching" name, you fargin sneaky bastage! (NOTE: This is a movie reference to "Johnny Dangerously") http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087507/quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unreal: I've been banging my head against the wall for hours and I'm embarrassed to say I solved my own problem. The solution?

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="    {Binding Path=name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="    {Binding Path=itemcount}"/>
```

Freaking name and itemcount weren't capitalized!!! Give me a second to punch myself in the face...annnnnd...I'm back now. Name and ItemCount are the proper way to code that.

Thanks anyway for the help all who responded.

Comment: been there so many times... 1001+ for punching yourself in the face!